# Ignore Unparseable JSON with jq

Tags: json, unix, logging, error-handling, jq

I'm using jq to parse some of my logs, but some of the log lines can't be parsed for various reasons. Is there a way to have jq ignore those lines? I can't seem to find a solution. I tried to use the --seq argument that was recommended by some people, but --seq ignores all the lines in my file.

Comment: The question is not about the individual lines which can't be parsed. It's about ignoring or bypassing the lines with issues. Imagine have a line that is just "123".

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Assuming that each log entry is exactly one line, you can use the `-R` or `--raw-input` option to tell jq to leave the lines unparsed, after which you can prepend `fromjson? |` to your filter to make jq try to parse each line as JSON and throw away the ones that error.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It took me a while to understand since I don't know much jq but this was just was I was looking for to remove some bad records from a file. For others like me, a way to use would be: 
```cat file_to_clean.jsonl | jq -R "fromjson? | . " -c > clean_file.jsonl```

Comment: If you want to convert unparsable lines to strings (like I needed to), you can prepend your script with `(. as $line | try fromjson catch $line) |`.

Comment: I found `tail -f log | jq -R 'try fromjson catch .'` enough for most cases

Comment: I'm using this for `kubectl` tailing logs for those pods spitting out JSON on std-out. It actually prints the fields that I need, while omitting others. Adapt to your needs :-) `kubectl logs -f --tail 200 <podname> | jq -R 'fromjson? | . | "\(.["@timestamp"]) -- \(.level) -- \(.logger_name) -- \(.message) \(.stack_trace)"' -r`

Comment: I wanted to run a script on the JSON lines and echo the rest as-is, this was what did it for me: `jq --raw-input '. as $line | try (fromjson | MY-JQ-SCRIPT) catch $line'`

Comment: Rather than having the try/catch lines, you could simply use: `fromjson? // .` If `fromjson?` fails to produce a value, use the input. Which is very different from `fromjson? | .`.

Answer (score 17):

This is an old thread, but here's another solution fully in `jq`. This allows you to both process proper json lines and also print out non-json lines:

```
jq -R '. as $line | try (fromjson) catch $line'
```

If you need to do additional jq processing:

```
jq -R . as $line | try (fromjson | <further processing for proper json lines>) catch $line'
```

Comment: This was great. Adapted it a bit so it works fully after a simple copy/paste: `jq -R '. as $line | try (fromjson) catch $line'`

Answer (score 14):

I have log stream where some messages are in json format.
I want to pipe the json messages through jq, and just echo the rest.

The json messages are on a **single line**.

**Solution:** use grep and tee to split the lines in two streams, those starting with "^{" pipe through jq and the rest just echo to terminal.

`kubectl logs -f web-svjkn | tee >(grep -v "^{") | grep "^{" | jq .`

or

`cat logs | tee >(grep -v "^{") | grep "^{" | jq .`

**Explanation:**
tee generates 2nd stream, and grep -v prints non json info, 2nd grep only pipes what looks like json opening bracket to jq.

Comment: This only checks for lines starting with {, that doesn't mean they are valid JSON. How about this line: `{{`?

Comment: @StevenRoose yes, and even "{" followed by non json, but for log parsing where you either have lines that are json, or normal log lines that start with a date, not curly bracket, and filtering on first character is enough to split stream and pass only the json lines through jq.

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing as the *most valuable* answers were actually *in comments*.

> Assuming that each log entry is exactly one line, you can use the -R or --raw-input option to tell jq to leave the lines unparsed, after which you can prepend fromjson? | to your filter to make jq try to parse each line as JSON and throw away the ones that error.

If you don't quite understand what to do with it, like me, then this is the answer:

`cat file_to_clean.jsonl | jq -R "fromjson? | . " -c > clean_file.jsonl`

Given by **steven2308** on Apr 14, 2020.

I'm parsing the `json` returned from web server, and I need to see the returned header as well, while this method will not show anything other than `json`.

The comment

> I found `tail -f log | jq -R 'try fromjson catch .'` enough for most cases

by **Dennis C** on Apr 4, 2022 suits my purpose -- I can see the HTTP headers returned from web server now, even though they show up as errors like `Invalid numeric literal at line 1`. But that's OK for me as I just want to see the headers. I guess it'll suit most people's case when they're checking out logs, for otherwise the *context* would be missing with solution #1.

Answer (score 1):

There are several Q&As on the [FAQ page](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) dealing with the topic of "invalid JSON", but see in particular the Q:

> Is there a way to have jq keep going after it hits an error in the input file?

In particular, this shows how to use --seq.

However, from the the sparse details you've given (SO [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) a minimal example be given), it would seem it might be better simply to use `inputs`. The idea is to process one JSON entity at a time, using "try/catch", e.g.

```
def handle: inputs | [., "length is \(length)"] ;
def process: try handle catch ("Failed", process) ;
process
```

Don't forget to use the -n option when invoking jq.

See also [Processing not-quite-valid JSON](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#processing-not-quite-valid-json).

Comment: this seems to be using a lib, not the command-line `jq`

Comment: @MarkHu - Nope.  You can add your own functions using command-line jq (or command-line gojq), though typically you'd read the jq program using the -f command-line option.

Answer (score 0):

I see two goals of this question:

- Be able to get output regardless of errors in the input JSON
- Be able to track down where the error **is**.

the `yq` binary from https://github.com/mikefarah/yq is more permissive, so you can use that to output lines in mostly the same way as with `jq`.

In addition, if you have a JSON file with errors a simple comparison using some linux / bash shell magic can help a lot.

```bash
# Using GNU diff, ignoring whitespace
# ...and Bash Process Substitution to diff the output of the yq command
diff -w inputfile.json <(yq inputfile.json)
```

Example output - missing trailing comma:

```
13c13
<         "kind": "ConfigMap"
---
>       "kind": "ConfigMap",
```

[Bash Process Substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

Answer (score -2):

If JSON in curly braces {}:

`grep -Pzo '\{(?>[^\{\}]|(?R))*\}' | jq 'objects'`

If JSON in square brackets []:

`grep -Pzo '\[(?>[^\[\]]|(?R))*\]' | jq 'arrays'`

This works if there are no []{} in non-JSON lines.