# How to ignore broken JSON line in jq?

Tags: json, logging, error-handling, command-line-interface, jq

When using `jq` to handle log files, some lines might be broken, therefore `jq` throws errors and stop processing.

e.g. the complete log:

```json
{"level":"debug","time":"2021-09-24T19:42:47.140+0800","message":"sent send binary to ws server1","pid":41491,"cid":"32likw","num":1,"count":5120}
{"level":"debug","time":"2021-09-24T19:42:47.305+0800","message":"sent send binary to ws server2","pid":41491,"cid":"32likw","num":1,"count":5120}
{"level":"debug","time":"2021-09-24T19:42:47.469+0800","message":"sent send binary to ws server3","pid":41491,"cid":"32likw","num":1,"count":5120}
{"level":"debug","time":"2021-09-24T19:42:47.499+0800","message":"sent send binary to ws server4","pid":41491,"cid":"32likw","num":1,"count":5120}
{"level":"debug","time":"2021-09-24T19:42:47.581+0800","message":"sent send binary to ws server5","pid":41491,"cid":"32likw","num":1,"count":5120}
```

jq handles it well:

```sh
< snippet1.json jq -C -r '.message'
sent send binary to ws server1
sent send binary to ws server2
sent send binary to ws server3
sent send binary to ws server4
sent send binary to ws server5
```

the broken one (last part of line 3 is missing):

```json
{"level":"debug","time":"2021-09-24T19:42:47.140+0800","message":"sent send binary to ws server1","pid":41491,"cid":"32likw","num":1,"count":5120}
{"level":"debug","time":"2021-09-24T19:42:47.305+0800","message":"sent send binary to ws server2","pid":41491,"cid":"32likw","num":1,"count":5120}
{"level":"debug","time":"2021-09-24T19:42:47.469+0800","message":"sent send binary to ws server3","pi
{"level":"debug","time":"2021-09-24T19:42:47.499+0800","message":"sent send binary to ws server4","pid":41491,"cid":"32likw","num":1,"count":5120}
{"level":"debug","time":"2021-09-24T19:42:47.581+0800","message":"sent send binary to ws server5","pid":41491,"cid":"32likw","num":1,"count":5120}
```

`jq` stops at the broken line:

```sh
< snippet2.json jq -C -r '.message'
sent send binary to ws server1
sent send binary to ws server2
parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 4, column 2
```

And I hope `jq` can ignore the 3rd line and continue, just like this:

```sh
< snippet2.json jq -C -r '.message'
sent send binary to ws server1
sent send binary to ws server2
sent send binary to ws server4
sent send binary to ws server5
```

I tried to use `-R` mentioned in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599314/ignore-unparseable-json-with-jq), it didn't help with this case.

```sh
< snippet2.json jq -C -R -r '.message'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "message"
jq: error (at <stdin>:2): Cannot index string with string "message"
jq: error (at <stdin>:3): Cannot index string with string "message"
jq: error (at <stdin>:4): Cannot index string with string "message"
jq: error (at <stdin>:5): Cannot index string with string "message"
```

Can you please let me know if there is any solutions/skills to ignore/skip/suppress errors like this and get result of the rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few more explanations to peak's answer. (Credits go to peak)

Solution #1:

```sh
❯ cat bad.json | jq -r -R 'fromjson? | .message'
sent send binary to ws server1
sent send binary to ws server2
sent send binary to ws server4
sent send binary to ws server5
```

Solution #2:

```sh
❯ cat bad.json | jq -r -R '. as $line | try fromjson catch $line | .message'
sent send binary to ws server1
sent send binary to ws server2
jq: error (at <stdin>:3): Cannot index string with string "message"
sent send binary to ws server4
sent send binary to ws server5
```

jq still output errors, but it's on stderr, and you can redirect it:

```sh
❯ cat bad.json | jq -r -R '. as $line | try fromjson catch $line | .message' 2>/dev/null
sent send binary to ws server1
sent send binary to ws server2
sent send binary to ws server4
sent send binary to ws server5
```

It's notable that it `-R` and`-r` can be used together. (Thanks for @peak !)

Comment: One can use -R and -r together.

Answer (score 7):

To skip the broken lines you could use:

```
jq -Rr 'fromjson? | .message'
```

If you want to do something else with them, you could start with something like:

```
jq -R '. as $line | try fromjson catch $line'
```

For other options, see:

> : Is there a way to have jq keep going after it hits an error in the input file? Can jq handle broken JSON?

in the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: OK. Let me edit my question. Thanks for your reminders.

Answer (score -1):

I also came across this issue. Briefly, here's our setup:

- Kubernets / AKS
- Datadog for log collection
- Maven for Java Spring Boot with `logstash-logback-encoder` dependency

Now `kubectl` logs become pretty unreadable on the commandline. However, I think debugging in the terminal still has its advantages. So here's my most loved one-line solution for more or less resilient live tailing from a kubernetes pod and quick debugging:

`kubectl logs -f --tail 200 <podname> | jq -R 'fromjson? | . | "\(.["@timestamp"]) -- \(.level) -- \(.logger_name) -- \(.message) \(.stack_trace)"' -r`

This will ignore/hide lines with parse errors and show some of the JSON fields of each log line using the format string above.

It's not perfect, but will serve as a starting point I guess. Adapt to your needs :-)